# Convert DataTable to array for highcharts

Tags: c#, highcharts, datatable

I want to provide data for highcharts from server.
I have a datatable like below:

```
DAY TIP  RESULT
1   0    1
1   2    53
2   2    3458
3   2    4197
3   0    495
4   2    5084
5   2    3408
6   NULL 22
6   0    2242
7   2    38
```

How can I retrieve proper data from this datatable?
I have tried so far two foreach loop. Is there more efficient way for this?

Finally, I want to have data like below:

```
Days = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

RESULT for each TIP due to days 

{ name: '0',
  data: [1,0,495,0,0,2242,0]
},
{ name: 'NULL',
  data: [0,0,0,0,0,22,0]
},
{ name: '2',
  data: [53,3458,4197,5084,3408,0,38]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use LINQ for this.

```
//Prepare
var items = new List<C1>();
items.Add(new C1 { Day = 1, Tip = 2, Result = 2000 });
items.Add(new C1 { Day = 1, Tip = 1, Result = 3000 });
items.Add(new C1 { Day = 2, Tip = 3, Result = 4000 });
items.Add(new C1 { Day = 2, Tip = 4, Result = 5000 });
items.Add(new C1 { Day = 2, Tip = 4, Result = 8000 });

//Group the days
var days = items.GroupBy(o => o.Day).Select(o => o.Key).ToList();

//Group the data on Tip
var tip = items.GroupBy(o => o.Tip, o => o.Result, (key, g) => new { Name = key, Data = g.ToList() }).ToList();
```

Class C1

```
public class C1
{
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Tip { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
}
```